ruff format document on save in VS Code *for real*
How do I convince ruff and VS Code to actually Format document on save? What I mean is that when I save a Python file, and do "Ruff: Format document", I get different results. I want saving a file to also run "Ruff: Format Document." How do I do that?
For example, if I start with
import os
import abc

def what():
    return 'hey'

when I save the document I get:

def what():
    return "hey"

with  "Ruff: Format document" I get:
import os
import abc


def what():
    return "hey"

Note that in both cases the single quoted 'hey' was fixed to double quoted "hey" which is good.
How do I get saving the document to do "Ruff: Format document"?
Here's pertinent section of my settings.json
  "[python]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "file",
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "charliermarsh.ruff",
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
    "editor.insertSpaces": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.fixAll": "explicit",
      "source.organizeImports": "explicit"
    }
  },



I've also run into this issue. One thing that might be related is when you set "ruff.lint.run": "onSave" you can see in Output window under Ruff 2024-12-16 13:56:36.617 [info] Running Ruff with: /dev_local/venv_Linux/bin/ruff ['check', '--force-exclude', '--no-cache', '--no-fix', '--quiet', '--output-format', 'json', '-', '--stdin-filename', 'my_file.py'] - notice the --no-fix
